# Is there a way to pull custom fields created in Pods plugin into a Elementor posts widget

Tags: wordpress, filter, widget, custom-post-type, elementor

I'm pretty new to WordPress but have been experimenting with the Pods plugin for custom post types and fields and trying to implement them using the Elementor page builder. Creating the post type and fields is all straight forward but I'd like to be able to now implement these custom fields into my pages. Specifically, I'd like to be able to integrate them with the Posts widget in Elementor.

By using the Ele Custom Theme plugin I have been able to create a Loop template and setup the articles I'd like to loop through and this method works fine using the standard Posts widget in Elementor. However, the standard Posts widget does not have the ability to add a filter to your items. This is what I need.

There is a Ultimate Addons version of the Posts widget that incorporates this filter function but it doesn't seem to have a feature to loop through a loop template. In the standard Posts widget, you are able to select a 'Custom' skin which can then hook up with the loop template you've created. The Ultimate Add Ons version doesn't have this option.

I hope I'm explaining this correctly and that someone maybe able to offer some advice.

Is it possible to for the Ultimate Addons version of the Posts widget to pull through a custom template like the standard version does. I have added an image as a guide. The Ultimate addons version is on the left hand side.

[image: Ultimate Addons version is on the left hand side and standard version is on the right]

Any advice on this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can use Livemesh Addons for Elementor,

https://wordpress.org/plugins/addons-for-elementor

with that you can create and select custom templates for post and custom post types.